# Accurate number of views

Tags: feature-request, view-counter

Maybe this isn't the appropriate place to mention this. But I noticed that the count of views increases (in particular for a question I asked) if I refresh my browser while on that question.

Certainly I have no intention to increase my view count. Maybe this is a negligible issue for a few extra views. But thought I would mention it.

Comment: Related older post: [Does the “viewed” counter also count the poster's view?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22760/does-the-viewed-counter-also-count-the-posters-view) (However, it is not a feature request.) There is also this feature request on meta.SO: [Do not count views of the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/do-not-count-views-of-the-asker)

Answer (score 4):

The number of views could well increase because of *other* users viewing the question page between the page refreshes on your computer.

According to [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated) a visitor is identified by either their account (if logged in) or IP address (if not). Consecutive pageloads by the same visitor within 15 minutes count as one view. After 15 minutes, it's an additional view.

The number says that it measures *views*, not unique visitors to the page -- therefore, counting the same person more than once is by design. And the fact that you happen to be the author of the question makes no difference. The question author could be visiting the page to read answers or comments; there is no reason to remove them from statistics.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but it could be that the number you first see is the number of *previous* people who have viewed the page, and that once the system "knows" your browser has loaded the page, it increments the number by one, so that when you hit refresh, it uploads the new number, which now includes your first view.  If you hit refresh again, the number no longer increments.  At least that's what I saw happen when I played around with a few random pages I hadn't viewed before -- the first refresh made the number go up, but later refreshes did not.

What makes me think the systems waits to increment the number until it "knows" you've viewed the page is that a few times (initially by accident, and then intentionally) I hit refresh before the page had finished loading and saw that the number did *not* go up by one, but if I hit refresh again after allowing the upload to finish it *did* go up (but not for any subsequent refreshment).